# git clone and checkout specific tags

Tags: git, tags, ansible, gitlab, pipeline

I am working on a gitlab project with its own git repository with Ansible roles.

The thing is that we also have some shared roles that are maintained by another team. These roles  are in a separate project, and each role is like a subproject with its own repository. Right now in our pipeline we do a git clone of those roles from the runner, execute the code and remove the clone again.

While this mechanism works well, the approach causes an issue. Say we deploy to development, test and acceptance, and then the shared roles get updated by the other team. By the time we deploy to production we will get inconsistencies as the shared roles that are cloned have changed.

So I thought of introducing git tags. Every commit on the shared roles get tagged with a version number. We can then do a git clone, and a checkout of the version number.

I am struggling however to get my head around how to implement this in the pipeline. Is there a way to do this without having to hard-code version numbers in the pipeline?

Comment: Tags of commit IDs — don't matter. What matters is you have to create a map that maps commits in your repository to tags (or commits) in the shared roles repo. There're many possible ways to store such a map; you can store it in a text file or in a pipeline script. You can also add the shared roles repo as a submodule to your repository; git maintains said commit map with submodules itself.

Comment: A colleague here said something similar and to store this info in Artifcatory. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have the *same* scenario where playbooks are sharing roles.

We looked at:

- tags
- submodules (yikes)
- subrepos

In the end, we went for neither: each of your playbooks include, as a `roles/` folder a symlink to parent folder of *all* our roles.
That way, a playbook always reference the latest version (currently checked out) of a role.

ansible keep referencing a specific SHA1 of a playbook, but the consensus remains: always use the latest of the roles. Without managing any specific Git references (when it comes to Git repos for each roles)